# How could I update the specific duplicated items in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to  update my Original document into expected document

That is remove the duplicated consecutive same price record,

only keep the last one.

How to do it with mongo query  ?

## Expected Document

```
{
  "_id": "2015-06-12-TPE-KIX",
  "flight_date": new Date("2015-06-12T08:00:00+0800"),
  "history": [
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433515526965),
      "price": 6740
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433607771762),
      "price": 5490
    }
  ]
}
```

## Original Document

```
{
  "_id": "2015-06-12-TPE-KIX",
  "flight_date": new Date("2015-06-12T08:00:00+0800"),
  "history": [
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433492046834),
      "price": 6740
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433492048208),
      "price": 6740
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433492428642),
      "price": 6740
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433492430039),
      "price": 6740
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433515526965),
      "price": 6740
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433562561356),
      "price": 5490
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433603772299),
      "price": 5490
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1433607771762),
      "price": 5490
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use the aggregation framework as a means to reduce the array to the required items and then update each document in the collection with the results. Shell example only, but the same base logic applies:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$history" },

    // Group by price on each document
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "_id": "$_id",
            "flight_date": "$flight_date",
            "price": "$history.price"
        },
        "updated_at": { "$max": "$history.updated_at" }
    }},

    // Sort by updated_at in each document
    { "$sort": { "_id._id": 1, "updated_at": 1 } },

    // Group back per document
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "flight_date": { "$first": "$_id.flight_date" },
        "history": {
            "$push": {
                "updated_at": "$updated_at",
                "price": "$_id.price"
            }
        }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "history": doc.history }
    });
    count++;

    // Send to server every 1000 and re-init
    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

// Process any queued 
if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

So that reduces down the array in results to what you want like so:

```js
{
    "_id" : "2015-06-12-TPE-KIX",
    "flight_date" : ISODate("2015-06-12T00:00:00Z"),
    "history" : [
            {
                    "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-06-05T14:45:26.965Z"),
                    "price" : 6740
            },
            {
                    "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:22:51.762Z"),
                    "price" : 5490
            }
    ]
}
```

But if you are actually updating the documents, I would do the array reduction rather in code per each document read by the cursor, and then send the similar bulk update requests per document.

The `$unwind` operation has significant overhead over a collection of documents, and since you are not actually "aggregating" across documents the approach of manipulating your array in client code would be the most efficient thing to do.

Of course, if you can live with a new collection or are happy to rename collections, then use the [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) option with the aggregation as shown above.